# How to avoid Doxygen inserting a newline between period and paren?

Tags: doxygen

Here is the input comment:

```
/** @page foo_test
1.2.(3).4
*/
```

Desired result:

> 1.2.(3).4

Actual result:

> 1.2.
>
> (3).4

Does anybody know why Doxygen does this and how I can make it stop? Substituting in [] or {} does not change the behavior.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? I tries 1.8.6 and in the html version it looks OK to me.

Comment: Was using 1.6.3, now upgraded to 1.7.3 (the latest version for which I could find a backport to Ubuntu Lucid, which is what I'm running). Was able to replicate the problem there, both in HTML and RTF. Guess I'll need to build 1.8.6 from source and try again.

Comment: I think it is good to upgrade to 1.8.6, I tried 1.6.3 and 1.7.3 on Windows and didn't see the problem. Any special settings in the Doxyfile?